# how to Merge more than two video in android

Tags: android

I am new to android

I want to merge more than two videos.like I have taken one video file from sdCard after second video is taken from the camera.now I want to merge both the video file in single video file.

I have tried several options but didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mp4parse https://code.google.com/archive/p/mp4parser/wikis/AppendTracks.wiki . If you have more 2 videos. Merge 1 vs 1 to end of files.

Comment: i already tried above link but not getting success .do you have any example of it  ?